# Adding First and Last buttons in Navigation Bar

Tags: cocoa-touch

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

Home (Table View) > (Click on row) > Move to 2nd View (Table View) > (Click on row) > Move to 3rd View (Table View) - SAVE or DONE button in navigation bar should take the user to Home (Table View).

A sample code will be very helpful.

Thanks

---

Mustafa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. This behavior is specifically pointed out as an example of what NOT to do.

Allow the user to go forward and backward one screen at a time. There should be no breadcrumb-like control.